# T-SQL: SUM Number between Delimiters from String

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, type-conversion

I need to get numbers with a variable length out of a string and sum them.

The strings got the following format:

```
EH:NUMBER=SomeOtherStuff->Code
```

I'm extracting the code via `RIGHT()` and join with another table to get the group right, at the moment I'm using sum to get it together via date:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (MONTH(data.DATE1) = 5  AND YEAR(data.DATE1) = YEAR(GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) N'Mai',
```

I then need to sum the numbers from the string and not the number of rows.

Some Examples:

```
Month1 EH:1=24->ZTM
Month1 EH:4=13-21->LKm
Month2 EH:3=34,33,43->LKm
Month2 EH:7=12,92-29,29->LKm
Month2 EH:5=24-26,11,21,22->ZOL
```

What i need:

```
Material - Month1 - Month2
ZTM - 1 - 0
LKM - 4 - 10
ZOL - 0 - 5
```

Could you help me please?

Greetings

Comment: Give us an example and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: 
What you are looking for is SUBSTRING.

Longer version:
To get the the sum of the numerical value of NUMBER you need think about how break it down.

I'd recommend following these steps:

1. Extract the NUMBER part from the string. This should be done with SUBSTRING (much like you extract Code with RIGHT). To get the start and and length och your substring use charindex ( or patindex if you like).
2. Convert the NUMBER part to a numerical value with cast (or convert or what you are familiar with)
3. Now you can do your aggregation.

So SUM(CAST(SUBSTRING(*this part you will have to figure out by yourself)) as *correct numerical data type*)). 
I'll let you figure out the values to insert by yourself and would recommend to first find the positions of the delimiting characters, then extract the NUMBER part, then get the numerical value .... you get it .

This to gain a better understanding of what you are actually doing.

Cheers, and good luck with your assignment
Martin